# How to Check for Multiple Conditions in Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to retrive `PName` of the  **row/field whose id =2 and pAddress=INDIA**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump >
<database name="MyDb">
<table name="DescriptionTable">
<row>
<field name="id">1</field>
<field name="pName">XYZ</field>
<field name="pAddress">INDIA</field>
<field name="pMobile">1234567897</field>
</row>
<row>
<field name="id">2</field>
<field name="pName">PQR</field>
<field name="pAddress">UK</field>
<field name="pMobile">755377</field>
</row>
<row>
<field name="id">3</field>
<field name="pName">ABC</field>
<field name="pAddress">USA</field>
<field name="pMobile">67856697</field>
</row>
</table>
</database>
</mysqldump>

String expression="/mysqldump/database[@name='MyDb']/table[@name='DescriptionTable']/row/field[@name='id' and ./text()]";
```

**Edit:**

I would like to get Pname whoese id is 2 and pAddress=INDIA

```
String expression="/mysqldump/database[@name='MyDb']/table[@name='DescriptionTable']/row/field[@name='id' and .='2']and[@name='pAddress' and .='INDIA']/../field[@name='pName']/text()";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the above answers could be improved by moving aspects of the path expression into the predicates, and using nested nested predicates. IMHO this makes the XPath selection much more human readable.

First we find the `row` with the `field` whose `@name eq id` and `text() = "2"`, from there we can simply select the `field` from that `row` whose the `@name eq "pName"`.

```
/mysqldump/database[@name = "MyDb"]/table[@name = "DescriptionTable"]/row[field[@name eq "id"][text() = "2"]]/field[@name = "pName"]
```

Also note the explicit use of `eq` and `=`, eq is used for comparing atomic values, in this instance the selection of our attributes, and `=` is used for comparing sequences (as it is conceivable that text() may return more than one item - although it won't for your example XML).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/mysqldump/database[@name='MyDb']/table[@name='DescriptionTable']/row/field[@name='id'][.='2']/following-sibling::field[@name='pName']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/mysqldump/database/table/row/field[@name='id' and .=2]/../field[@name='pName']
```

Explanation:

```
/mysqldump/database/table/row/field[@name='id' and .=2]
```

gets the field where id name attribute= id and the value equals 2

```
../
```

goes to the parent node.

```
field[@name='pName']
```

searches the field where attribute name contains pName

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this way :

```
/mysqldump
/database[@name='MyDb']
/table[@name='DescriptionTable']
/row[
        field[@name[.='id'] and .=2] 
            and 
        field[@name[.='pAddress'] and .='INDIA']
    ]
/field[@name='pName']
```

Above XPath will select `<row>` element whose id is 2 and pAddress=INDIA, then get the row's pName. But looking at the sample XML in this question, there is no such `<row>` that fulfill both criteria. If you meant to select row which either has id equals `2` or has pAddress equals `INDIA`, you can use `or` instead of `and` in the row filtering expression :

```
/mysqldump
/database[@name='MyDb']
/table[@name='DescriptionTable']
/row[
        field[@name[.='id'] and .=2] 
            or 
        field[@name[.='pAddress'] and .='INDIA']
    ]
/field[@name='pName']
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way to achieve the above is

```
String expression = "/mysqldump/database[@name='MyDb']/table[@name='DescriptionTable']/
    row[./field[@name="id"]/text()="2" and ./field[@name="pAddress"]/text()="INDIA"]
/field[@name="pName"]/text()";
```

You can add multiple conditions in the second line seperated by and/or based on your needs

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to get text from two `pName`s.

I think this should work for you in scope of current xml:

```
//row/field[text()='2' OR text()='INDIA']/../field[@name='pName']/text()
```

If you want to take just nodes:

```
//row/field[text()='2' OR text()='INDIA']/../field[@name='pName']
```